# GraphiQL is not sending cookies?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, graphiql

I've got a Spring Boot App that gains GraphQL by way of `org.springframework.experimental/graphql-spring-boot-starter`. That starter, somehow, gives me the GraphiQL UI to run ad-hoc queries through. As I tried to integrate Spring Security into my Application all of my `POST /graphql` calls began to see 403 at the browser.

[image]

Looking at the Chrome console, I can see the root cause. Our auth rides on a cookie bound to the domain. The GraphiQL client is failing to send the cookie, so Spring Security can't find anything to authenticate. When I copy the request as curl, I can see it is missing the Cookie header...

```
$ curl 'http://localhost.example.com:8080/graphql' \
>   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
>   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
>   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36' \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   -H 'Origin: http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080' \
>   -H 'Referer: http://localhost.blueorigin.com:8080/?path=/graphql' \
>   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
>   --data-raw '{"query":"query now {\n  now\n}","variables":null,"operationName":"now"}' \
>   --compressed \
>   --insecure
{"timestamp":"2021-10-13T19:18:37.223+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/graphql"}
```

If I give curl the Cookie the server needs...all is well.

How do I get GraphiQL to send cookies for a Spring Boot Application?

Comment: The "Request Headers" thing on the GraphiQL UI does not appear to do anything. When I put "Cookie" and the token there the Chrome Console shows no change.

Comment: The "Request Headers" thing IS capable of transiting an Authorization header. Sadly, you can't configure it with one Bearing our JWT Token after it fails on GraphQL Schema interrogation. At org.springframework.experimental/graphql-spring-boot-starter 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 2021-10-13, this looks like an unfixable problem.